# Post select option PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, formmail

I cannot figure out how to POST select options. The form posts empty values for the contact (option) field. I know the selected_val is incorrect but not sure how to correct.

The form posts fine, but contact returns an empty value. Can anyone help out with how to correct the PHP.

**Here's the PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $selected_val = $_POST['contact']; "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From your website'; 
    $to = 'somedomain.com'; 
    $subject = 'Visitor Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\nCity: $city\nContact: $contact\nMessage: $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    // Check if business has been entered
    if (!$_POST['company']) {
        $errBusiness = 'Please enter your business or organization name';
    }

    // Check if phone has been entered
    if (!$_POST['phone']) {
        $errPhone = 'Please enter your phone number';
    }

    // Check if phone has been entered
    if (!$_POST['phone']) {
        $errPhone = 'Please enter the name of your city';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! 
            We will be in touch soon.</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-elements" role="form" method="post" action="services-form.php">           
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <label for="contact">Contact preference</label>                                
        <select class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact">
            <option>Email</option>
            <option>Phone</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: value attribute missing

Comment: Check `POST` data before using it to make sure it's being posted. `echo "<pre>",print_r($_POST),"</pre>";` - never forget it's just an array.

Comment: Not sure I get what you are suggesting. Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 3):

value attribute missing It should be like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact">
 <option>select</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yup sure it is - duh! So after fixing this the option value is still posting nothing. I think this is incorrect: 
 $selected_val = $_POST['contact']; "You have selected :" .$selected_val;

Comment: you have to select anyone either email or phone then you have to submit the form because first optin is empty .

Comment: echo missing  $selected_val = $_POST['contact']; echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;

Comment: I get ya, but that's not working either. Reload page and select option second option (phone) but it still posts nothing.

Comment: print_r($_POST); exit; on destination page and know the all post values

Comment: Figured it out -> $selectOption = $_POST['contact'];

Answer (score 1):

You need `value` on option tags.

```
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="phone">Phone</option>
```

And I don't see any input name `submit` in your HTML

```
if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
```

If so, it's not even go in to your code.

Also this line of your PHP code is doing nothing.

```
"You have selected :" .$selected_val;
```

should be

```
print "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
```

or

```
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
```

Comment: first line of PHP 
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $selected_val = $_POST['contact']; "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From your website'; 
        $to = 'somedomain.com'; 
        $subject = 'Visitor Inquiry';

Comment: Yes, I see it in PHP but not in the HTML. you may need something like `<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='submit'>` in your HTML.